# How to found a spesific word with PHP from txt file?

Tags: php, search, text

I have a PHP script to found a keyword from txt file but the results are showing a whole line. In this case, I want the results just showing the specific word.

This the txt source file :

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet aaaaa@xxx.com, consectetur adipiscing bbbbb@xxx.com elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 

labore et dolore magna aliqua cccc@xxx.com. 

Ut enim ad minim veniam ddd@xxx.com, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea jjjj@xxx.com commodo 

consequat. 

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 

occaecat cupidatat non proident@xxx.com, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim@xxx.com id est laborum.
```

I use this PHP code :

```
<?php
$file = 'D:\tes.txt';
$searchfor = 'xxx.com';

// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Found matches:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}

?>
```

With that code the results is :

```
Found matches:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet aaaaa@xxx.com, consectetur adipiscing bbbbb@xxx.com elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua cccc@xxx.com. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam ddd@xxx.com, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea jjjj@xxx.com commodo consequat. 
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident@xxx.com, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim@xxx.com id est laborum.
```

But i want like this :

```
aaaaa@xxx.com
bbbbb@xxx.com
ddd@xxx.com
cccc@xxx.com
jjjj@xxx.com
.........
.....
```

Needs some help please because i have no idea with coding but i needs this script.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You match the whole line because you are using `.*` and anchors `^` and `$` to assert the start and the end of the line. To match all the email addresses you could update your `$pattern` to:

`$pattern = "/\S+@xxx\.com\b/m";`

Your code could look like:

```
$file = 'D:\tes.txt';
// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$pattern = "/\S+@xxx\.com/m";
// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
    echo "Found matches:\n";
    echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
    echo "No matches found";
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/7ival)

That will match not a whitespace character one or more times `S+`, and `@` sign followed by `xxx.com` and at the end a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`

Comment: Thank you it's work.. And if i want to use some a kind of keyword like "xxx.com, +3523 and +1304" what i should add? Thank you..

Comment: That depends on what you expect to match. If you want to find words you might use word boundaries `\b` but if you want to find a specific pattern then you have to define that pattern.